# Using requireJS with angular; Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

Ok, there is a bunch of questions with similar titles, but none of them helped me solve my problem so here it is.

I am trying to use Angular with RequireJS; I am getting the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined` which is referring to the `angular` object within the `angular-routes.js file`. This suggests to me that requireJS is trying to load angular-routes before angular has loaded. I was under the impression that this wouldn't happen because I have set 'angular-route' as dependant on 'angular' within the shim. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong here?

```
// Setup requireJS

require.config({

    baseUrl : "scripts",

    packages : [
        { "name":"angular", "location":"../bower_components/angular", "main":"angular"},
        { "name":"angular-route", "location":"../bower_components/angular-route", "main":"angular-route"},
        { "name":"angular-animate", "location":"../bower_components/angular-animate", "main":"angular-animate"},
        { "name":"angular-storage", "location":"../bower_components/angular-storage/dist", "main":"angular-storage"},
        { "name":"jquery", "location":"../bower_components/jquery/dist", "main":"jquery"}
],

   shim:{
        'angular' : { exports : 'angular', deps : ['jquery'] },
        'angular-route' : { deps : ['angular'] },
        'angular-animate' : { deps : ['angular'] },
        'angular-storage' : { deps : ['angular'] },
    }

});

// Load app files
function loadApp($, app)
{
    angular.element(document).ready(function(){
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['mealPlannerApp']);    
    });
}
requirejs(['app'], loadApp);
```

My `app.js` file is as follows

```
(function() {

    // Declare AMD module with dependencies
    define(['angular', 'angular-route', 'routes'],

    function(config)
    {

        var app = angular.module('mealPlannerApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAnimate']);
        app.config(config);
    });

}());
```

Comment: seems like you have injected same module twice `ngAnimate` like `angular.module('mealPlannerApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAnimate']);`

Comment: True - thanks. That was a typo though; problem still persists...

Comment: I see quite a few bugs in your code (but these don't explain the above error). I think you need to require "angular-animate" too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages are great for your internal packages, I haven’t tried to load main AngularJS files as them.

Please read http://jonathancreamer.com/require-js-packages-for-building-large-scale-angular-applications/ for some better clarification and examples than change config section to something like this. Major change is  replacement of  **packages** with **paths**

Please also consider to change variables to camelCase style

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        angular: '../bower_components/angular/angular',
        'angular-route': '../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route',
        'angular-animate': '../bower_components/angular-route/angular-animate',
        'angular-storage': '../bower_components/angular-route/angular-storage'
    },

    shim: {
        'angular' : { exports : 'angular', deps : ['jquery'] },
        'angular-route' : { deps : ['angular'] },
        'angular-animate' : { deps : ['angular'] },
        'angular-storage' : { deps : ['angular'] },
    },

    priority: [
        "angular"
    ]
});
```